# VECM lag 1 => is 1-1=0 , or VAR (-1) , or VAR at difference. which one?

Tags: vector-error-correction-model

When I run a regression, all variables are I(1), the optimal lag according to SIC is one, and means I should do VECM (1-1=0) the coefficient of the error correction term (ECT) is negative but not significant. My question is:

1. can I do VAR instead of VECM,
2. Should I do VAR of differencs: means in E-views: D(dependent Variable) D(Variable1) D(Variable2) D(Variable3)..and so on. Or VAR (-1) means VAR one lag.

Answer (score 1):

it depends on :
first: look at the rank in the johansen co-integration test, if it is full, not full or null.
if the rank is full ---> run VAR.
If the rank not full ---> vecm.
If the rank in null ---> defferenciate and then run VAR.
Michel Johansen.
Sun University.